# error shown call mysql stored procedure in query browser

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, mysql-workbench

I have created a stored procedure in mysql. When I call the procedure in mysql query browser it shows error "procedure dose not exist" but I am sure that the stored procedure exists in the database.I don't know where I am going wrong. Please help anyone

This is my Stored Procedure Code

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `aad_adr`.`  MonthlySalesReport(IN fromdate DATE,IN todate DATE)` $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `aad_adr`.`  MonthlySalesReport(IN fromdate DATE,IN todate DATE)` ()
BEGIN
Declare fd DATE;
Declare ed DATE;
SET fd=fromdate;
SET ed=todate;
WHILE DATE(fd)<=DATE(ed)DO
select bill_master.bill_no,DATE_FORMAT(bill_master.bill_date, '%y/%m/%d') AS 'formatted_date',transaction.product_id,transaction.tax_amount,transaction.amount,transaction.amount-transaction.tax_amount as 'without_tax ',product_master.Product_name,product_master.vat from bill_master inner join transaction on bill_master.bill_no=transaction.bill_no inner join product_master on transaction.product_id=product_master.product_id where vat='14.50' and bill_master.bill_date=fd;
SET fd=DATE_ADD(fd,INTERVAL 1 DAY);
END WHILE;
END $$

DELIMITER;
```

calling statement:

```
CALL MonthlySalesReport('2016-03-06','2016-03-07');
```

error:

```
PROCEDURE aad_adr.MonthlySalesReport does not exist
```

Comment: First check that store processor is exist in database or not with this command.... SHOW CREATE PROCEDURE `MonthlySalesReport(IN fromdate DATE,IN todate DATE)`

Answer (score 1):

Stored procedure create and drop statement have some problem, it have some space before name. Remove space and run command `aad_adr`.`

```
MonthlySalesReport(IN fromdate DATE, IN todate DATE)
```

Check space removed in below code.

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `aad_adr`.`MonthlySalesReport` $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `aad_adr`.`MonthlySalesReport`(IN fromdate DATE,IN todate DATE)
     BEGIN
       Declare fd DATE;
       Declare ed DATE;
       SET fd=fromdate;
       SET ed=todate;
       WHILE DATE(fd)<=DATE(ed)DO
             select bill_master.bill_no,DATE_FORMAT(bill_master.bill_date, '%y/%m/%d') AS 'formatted_date',transaction.product_id,transaction.tax_amount,transaction.amount,transaction.amount-transaction.tax_amount as 'without_tax ',product_master.Product_name,product_master.vat from bill_master inner join transaction on bill_master.bill_no=transaction.bill_no inner join product_master on transaction.product_id=product_master.product_id where vat='14.50' and bill_master.bill_date=fd;
          SET fd=DATE_ADD(fd,INTERVAL 1 DAY);
       END WHILE;
    END $$
DELIMITER;
```

Comment: @RamEswar, first check all stored procedure in db, then drop MonthlySalesReport procedure and create it again. Then try to call.

Comment: @RamEswar yes one more error i am correcting my answer

Comment: @RamEswar Accept answer